# Including a literal string in the regex

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

Current URLs:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?route=common/home
http://domain.com/index.php?route=account/register
http://domain.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart
http://domain.com/index.php?route=checkout/checkout
```

Desired URLs:

```
http://domain.com/home
http://domain.com/register
http://domain.com/cart
http://domain.com/checkout
```

Regex:

```
(?=\=)(.*?)(?<=\/).+$
```

... almost works, but it matches (for example the last URL) `=checkout/` whereas I need it to match `index.php?route=` as well so I can remove the whole `index.php?route=checkout/` from the URL.

I tried `index.php?route=(?=\=)(.*?)(?<=\/).+$` but ofcourse it doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? It's not clear.

Comment: My regex matches from `=` to `?` (including both chars), I need to include `index.php?route` as well in the match so I can replace the whole string so the new URL looks like `domain.com/home`

Comment: `index.php\?route=[a-z]*\/$`
[RegExr](http://regexr.com/) - a quite nice tool.

Comment: @Eldo.Ob `No match` on RegExr for that, nice tool nonetheless!

Comment: @3zzy oh yeah, just remove the '$'-at the end `index.php\?route=[a-z]*\/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the desired part, you should substitute:

```
index.php\?route\=[^\/]*\/
```

with an empty string.
To be more strict and precise, you should use lookbehind:

```
(?<=http:\/\/domain.com\/)index.php\?route\=[^\/]*\/
```

Check the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/sY7aV6/1

Comment: @3zzy I don't know if regexr.com works with PHP syntax or whatever.